# Changing fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to show different fragments depending on whether GPS is enabled or not. But I am getting this error :-

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e00a1
```

Please advise me how to do this:

Here is my MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Fragment fr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (!mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        fr = new FragmentTwo();
        getFragment();
    } else {
        fr = new FragmentOne();
        getFragment();
    }
}

public void getFragment() {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
  }
}
```

**FragmentOne:-**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
   }
}
```

**FragmentTwo:-**

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    } 
 }
```

My activity_main:-

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:name="com.test.FragmentTwo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the fragment_one.xml and fragment_two.xml are same just the different text:-

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="GPS IS ENABLE"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:name="com.test.FragmentTwo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

With

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

As static `Fragment` can not be replace at run time. But you can add or replace fragment in `FrameLayout`.

Comment: but now it giving java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  @Dhaval Patel

Comment: here is the link :- https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CDB5011499C666C7!422&authkey=!AIVQ_oh-JIvTbGM&ithint=file%2c   for the logcat file @Dhaval Patel

Comment: @ghost Are you sure you have replace whole `Fragment` tag with `FrameLayout` tag in `activity_main.xml`? From error it looks like it's still tring to find fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this line

```
 android:name="com.test.FragmentTwo"

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```